# CSS relative path broken when deploying to github pages, build process issue?

Tags: css, github, visual-studio-code, sass, github-pages

I built a very simple static page deployed to Github Pages.
I noticed quickly that most of the css background images failed to load.
After doing some digging around I found that the culprit is my SCSS/CSS.

In VSCode, my relative path for an image looks something like this:

```
  @media (min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 37.5em),
    (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) and (min-width: 37.5em),
    (min-width: 125em) {
    background-image: linear-gradient(
        to right bottom,
        rgba($color-primary-light, 0.801),
        rgba($color-primary-dark, 0.801)
      ),
      url(../../img/apple-mountains_1920.jpg);
```

However, this was causing the URL to become clipped, stepping backward out of the repository.

What it should be:

`https://name.gethub.io/repositoryname/img/apple-mountains_1920.jpg`

What I was getting:

`https://name.gethub.io/img/apple-mountains_1920.jpg`

To fix this, I simply needed to go through and remove one period from all of my background-image paths:

`url(../../img/apple-mountains_1920.jpg);`

Becomes:

`url(./../img/apple-mountains_1920.jpg);`

One thing that is interesting, is that in VSCode on my machine, if I don't use the format (../../img...) the file isn't found.

What am I doing wrong? I'm fairly new to deployment, is this going to be a problem with any webhost I use or is it something unique to Github pages?

Better yet, is there a way I can automate fix this in my build process?
Right now I just run my SCSS through this series:

`"compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.comp.css",
"concat:css": "concat -o css/style.concat.css css/icon-font.css css/style.comp.css",
"prefix:css": "postcss --use autoprefixer -b \"last 5 versions\" css/style.concat.css -o css/style.prefix.css",
"compress:css": "node-sass css/style.prefix.css css/main.css --output-style compressed",`

EDIT: 
My File tree structure is:

```
Project Folder
|- index.html
|- [css folder]
|- [img folder]
|- [js folder]
|- [sass folder]
|  |- main.scss
|  |- [abstracts]
|  |  |-_functions.scss
|  |  |-_mixins.scss
|  |  |-_variables.scss
|  |- [base]
|  |  |-_base.scss
|  |  |-_typography.scss
|  |  |-_utilities.scss
|  |- [components]
|  |  |-_buttons.scss
|  |  |-_form.scss
|  |  |-_cards.scss
|  |- [layout]
|  |  |-_footer.scss
|  |  |-_header.scss
|  |  |-_navigation.scss
|  |- [pages]
|  |  |-_home.scss
```

My development machine is Windows 10, if that makes a difference.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try that '../img/apple-mountains_1920.jpg'
If your file-tree look like

```
somefolder
    index.html
img
   thisImage
```

But what would be better - add your file-tree to question

Comment: Thanks! Added the file tree, since the relative paths coming from my SASS compile seems to be part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After digging around, it seems that the problem is due to me attempting to use a 7-1 style folder structure where the source SASS isn't in the same or similar structure to the CSS.

Seems that I might need to take advantage of a package like [resolve-url-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/resolve-url-loader) in order to fix the relative paths automatically.